# React-Router: Navigation based on value created in redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm trying to create a React.js version of https://rarwe-demo.pagefrontapp.com/bands using React-Router and Redux.

I would like to mimic the behaviour of the other app when a new band is created. Namely, navigate to the new band.

The URL of the app is `.../bands/<bandid>/songs`. I'm storing bands in an array and `<bandid>` is the index into the array and I don't know what that is until *after* it's created.

```
[
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Pearl Jam',
        songs: [
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Led Zeppelin',
        songs: [
            ...
        ]
    },
]
```

My first thought was dispatching another action. But that seems wrong to have a "changeUrl" action based on band name. Also, how would I do that in the correct order as the create operation could take a while?

It also feels wrong to store a "selectedBand" value in Redux as then I have to ensure the URL and this value is synchronised.

I presume there is a "standard" way of doing it, but my google-foo is failing me. I've been able to find lots of example of firing a Redux action based on a URL transition, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the bands and input box are listed inside a `MenuBar` component. You can write a `componentWillReceiveProps` method inside this component. And when a new Band is created, ensure that the reducer sends a response to the `MenuBar` component.

Now inside the `componentWillReceiveProps` write a condition that if a new band is created this gets executed.

```
browserHistory.push('/bands/<newbandid>/songs')
```

Comment: How do I "ensure that the reducer sends a response to the MenuBar component"? That sounds like adding something to the state which I think I should avoid

Comment: connectify the component. It will be able to access store. Read [redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the recommended way is to use Redux-Thunk https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1543#issuecomment-201364298

I haven't tried it yet, but something like this inside the:

```
dispatch(create_action);
get_new_id_from_state();
browserHistory.push(new_id);
```

I'll update this with the final code when I get the chance to actually do this.